# Как обратится к полю по его алиасу?

Tags: postgresql

Вот скриншоты поясняющие суть ситуации:

здесь мы создали поле с алиасом **cnt**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а здесь я пытаюсь к нему обратится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и получаю ошибку.

Вопрос: в чем причина такого поведения ведь первый скриншот доказывает что поле с таким именем присутствует, как надо правильно обращаться к таким полям?

Comment: Вы посмотрите порядок выполнения запроса и подумайте, когда именно у этого поля появляется имя - до выполнения WHERE или гораздо после... можете попробовать переместить условие из WHERE в HAVING, авось выстрелит. Хотя запрос какой-то странный - вернуть количество записей, если их не 777 штук...

Comment: @Akina я всегда считал что сначала формируется полная таблица а уже потом происходит отбор. если это не так значит это выражение нужно пихать в FROM а потом уже отбирать. Странно все это но ваша мысль мне ясна. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Akina да вы правы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как оно должно быть!

`select count(*) as cnt from users having count(*) = 777`

`having` срабатывает раньше, нежели у результирующего поля появляется `alias`